# Apex Item in interactive report not being displayed correctly

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm creating a interactive report and I want to dynamically create apex items (text fields) in it, but they are not being displayed correctly.

This is my code:

```
select 
APEX_ITEM.text( p_idx=> 1 , p_value=> null, p_item_id => 'dynamic_item') as "Textfield" 
from dual 
connect by level = 3;
```

This shows up in the report:

```
<input type="text" name="f01" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="" id="dynamic_item" />
```

But I would like to get the actual item and not the code?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't set the escape special characters property to `"No"`.

Go on your report and select the column you created (Textfield).

Then on the right at `"Security - Escape special characters"` select `"No"`.

Now it should be displayed correctly!